# GitLab Default Issue Template for all new Projects

Tags: automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline

I'm wondering if there is a way to set a default issue template for all new created projects? As a developer I often create new projects for every job I take. What I already have done is creating a default project template from which I create my new projects. So all the settings are always the same and I do not have to set the project up again from the scratch.
What I am missing is the part, where I can define default issue templates for all my projects, as the issue template is always the same, too. I know I can create a issue template for my projects by adding them to the issue-template directory in my repository. But how can i 'automate' this, to not have to add them manually? 
Can anyone help me out?

Greets 
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

2020: The notion of [template repository](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/instance_template_repository.html) is only for GitLab premium.

Locally, you could define ([`git init --template`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---templatelttemplatedirectorygt)) a template repo that would:

- be used for any new repository
- include your standard issue template file
- be pushed to your new GitLab repo.

---

Update 2022, for all GitLab tier:

See [GitLab 14.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/02/22/gitlab-14-8-released/#add-default-issue-and-merge-request-templates-in-a-projects-repository) (February 2022)

> ### Add default issue and merge request templates in a project’s repository
>
> In addition to defining [default issue and merge request description templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) in project settings, you can now set default templates in the `.gitlab`
> directory of a project’s repository.
>
> Do it by creating a `Default.md` file in the issue or merge request templates folders.
> If default templates exist in both the project’s settings and in the repository, the template in the settings
> takes precedence.
>
> Thanks for the contribution `@davebarr`!
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/description_templates.html#set-a-default-template-for-merge-requests-and-issues) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/2557).

Comment: This sounds really helpful, thanks! But if I change the issue template I also want it to be contributed to all my other projects. So i just have to change the template in on directory and not in all projects. Any hints for this?

Comment: @ThomasBerg That is the drawback of that approach: changing the template won't update any existing or new issues in existing repository.

Comment: Ok i tried this approach and it worked out, but as I said i would need to have somewhat like one project for the settings and the template, and everytime i change them, all other project could be updated. Maybe it can workout with GitLab CI / Pipeline ? Any ideas about this? Or does the premium version have all this already?

Comment: @ThomasBerg I don't think that modifying a template would modify projects *already* created from said template project, even in Premium. I don't know of any pipeline which would be able to go to all existing projects and "update" them.

Comment: Ok,, i see. Maybe it could work if each project would have its own pipeline to get the changes of the template? Pipelines would need to get triggerd manually i guess, or lets say on each push to the repo the pipeline would automatically overwrite the template issue with the one from the default template? I'm not that advanced in pipelines and GitLab CI. But that could be possible?

Comment: @ThomasBerg Not sure: getting (automatically) changes in a template is one thing. *Applying* those changes to an existing repo is another.